# Can I sheet mulch over perennial bulbs?

Tags: perennials, mulch

By sheet mulching I mean laying cardboard and then 2-3 inches of mulch on top of it.

I want to do this to an area with daffodils. Since they have already bloomed, is it ok to do this, and in theory, if the cardboard has biodegraded by next spring, will the daffodils grow back?

Comment: Has the daffodil foliage died back, or *will it have* before you start?

Comment: You would be better off with deeper mulch and no sheet cardboard - shredded is OK.

Comment: @Ecnerwal no, the daffodil blooms are gone but they still have green foliage. Should I wait until they’ve gone dormant?

Comment: Yes. The bulbs need the energy the leaves put into them to grow next spring.

Comment: Cardboard has been shown to kill your soil by completely shutting down the oxygen exchange between atmosphere and soil; newspaper and landscape fabric will do the same thing. As ecnerwal pointed out, it's not needed with a deep enough wood chip mulch (6 inches should do it). Wait until the daffodil leaves are yellowing before you do anything.